# Standard Enthalpy of Formation of H2(g) vs H(g)

Tags: enthalpy, hydrogen

My question is somewhat related to [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18898/why-is-the-standard-enthalpy-of-formation-of-o2-and-other-reference-forms-of-ele). When I look at a table of standard values there are two entries for Hydrogen:

- $\ce {H2(g)} $  - 0 kJ/mol
- $\ce {H(g)} $  -  218 kJ/mol

I understand the $\ce{H2(g)} $ is 0 because it is used as a reference, why is monatomic $\ce{ H(g)}$ given in the table and what does it mean? When would one use it in a calculation of enthalpy change?

From what I understand Hydrogen only exists as a monatomic gas at very high temperatures, the Standard enthalpies of formation are given at 1 bar, 298.15 K.

Comment: The value for the hydrogen atom is one-half the bond dissociation energy of the hydrogen molecule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value may be used whenever atomic hydrogen is present as a (probably intermediate) species. E.g. take the reaction

$$\ce{2H <=> H2}$$

which is the basic reaction in atomic hydrogen welding.

Comment: This is correct - often the relevant species is a lone proton. For example, in the formation of solid metal hydrides you need H to enter, diffuse, and react with the metal. H$_{2}$ just won't do it.

Comment: @JonCuster does that mean that we use the $\ce{H(g)}$ in Hess's law when we are looking at, for instance, the combustion of hydrogen with oxygen, since at some point monatomic hydrogen is an intermediate specie in that reaction?

Comment: Well, you get to choose your standard state, but you have to be consistent. The end result is the same, how you get there is slightly different.